# Hierarchy search in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, firebird, recursive-query

i have the following table

```
ID   CATALOGUE  SWID   PARENTSWID   LEVEL
1       1         1         1         0
2       1         2         1         1
3       1         3         1         1 
4       1         4         2         2
5       1         5         4         3
6       1         6         5         4
7       2         2         2         0
8       2         3         2         1
```

So I want all elements `(SWID)` which have the `PARENTSWID= "1"`.

The root level is always "`0`", and root element have the same `SWID` and `PARENTSWID`

There are no boundaries for the depth of the tree.
Later I will have to restrict the search with the `CATALOGUE` property, but for now I need an idea how to set this up.

So, has somebody done anything like this ? :)

Kind regards
Semir

---

```
WITH cte as
(
SELECT ID, CATALOGUE, SWID, PARENTSWID, LEVEL
FROM table
WHERE PARENTSWID = 1
AND LEVEL = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT t.ID, t.CATALOGUE, t.SWID, t.PARENTSWID, t.LEVEL
FROM table t
JOIN CTE ON cte.ID = t.PARENTSWID
AND t.LEVEL= cte.LEVEL+1
)
SELECT ID, CATALOGUE, SWID, PARENTSWID, LEVEL FROM cte;
```

when trying this i get the error "unknown ISC error 336397226". 
I have looked up this error and it means : `336397226 dsql_cte_cycle CTE '@1' has cyclic dependencies`

My table has the same items as the one here

(I have tried it on IBWSQL with my DB selected)

Comment: what is your expected output.

Comment: SWID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6) - because they are all descendants of parent = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution for Firebird SQL using Common Table Expressions.

```
CREATE TABLE STACKOVERFLOW0001 (
    ID          INTEGER,
    CATALOUGE   INTEGER,
    SWID        INTEGER,
    PARENTSWID  INTEGER,
    "LEVEL"     INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO STACKOVERFLOW0001 (ID, CATALOUGE, SWID, PARENTSWID, "LEVEL")
                       VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 0);
INSERT INTO STACKOVERFLOW0001 (ID, CATALOUGE, SWID, PARENTSWID, "LEVEL")
                       VALUES (2, 1, 2, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO STACKOVERFLOW0001 (ID, CATALOUGE, SWID, PARENTSWID, "LEVEL")
                       VALUES (3, 1, 3, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO STACKOVERFLOW0001 (ID, CATALOUGE, SWID, PARENTSWID, "LEVEL")
                       VALUES (4, 1, 4, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO STACKOVERFLOW0001 (ID, CATALOUGE, SWID, PARENTSWID, "LEVEL")
                       VALUES (5, 1, 5, 4, 3);
INSERT INTO STACKOVERFLOW0001 (ID, CATALOUGE, SWID, PARENTSWID, "LEVEL")
                       VALUES (6, 1, 6, 5, 4);
INSERT INTO STACKOVERFLOW0001 (ID, CATALOUGE, SWID, PARENTSWID, "LEVEL")
                       VALUES (7, 2, 2, 2, 0);
INSERT INTO STACKOVERFLOW0001 (ID, CATALOUGE, SWID, PARENTSWID, "LEVEL")
                       VALUES (8, 2, 3, 2, 1);

COMMIT WORK;

Query 

WITH RECURSIVE cat (id,catalouge,swid,parentswid,lvl)
as
(
    select id,catalouge,swid,parentswid,"LEVEL" from stackoverflow0001 as r
    where r."LEVEL" = 0 -- Magic Happens here for Filtering, you can specify the Start of the recursive tree walk down from here.


    union all

    select r.id, r.catalouge, r.swid, r.parentswid,r."LEVEL" from stackoverflow0001 as r,cat
    where cat.swid = r.parentswid -- This is what matches up the first query record to the child records
    and r."LEVEL" > 0 -- Just an additional filter check for child records.
)

select * from cat
// You can also stick some where clauses here if you need

Output

ID  CATALOUGE   SWID    PARENTSWID  LVL
1   1   1   1   0
2   1   2   1   1
4   1   4   2   2
5   1   5   4   3
6   1   6   5   4
8   2   3   2   1
3   1   3   1   1
7   2   2   2   0
4   1   4   2   2
5   1   5   4   3
6   1   6   5   4
8   2   3   2   1
8   2   3   2   1
```

Comment: wow, this seems to work :))))  but one question, is there any difference if i put some where clause in the statement after "Union all" and as you said after "select * from cat" (i mean difference regarding speed)

Answer (score 4):

This works with sqlserver 2005+

```
DECLARE @PARENTSWID int = 1
;WITH cte as
(
SELECT ID, CATALOGUE, SWID, PARENTSWID, LEVEL
FROM table
WHERE PARENTSWID = @PARENTSWID
AND LEVEL = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT t.ID, t.CATALOGUE, t.SWID, t.PARENTSWID, t.LEVEL
FROM table t
JOIN CTE ON cte.ID = t.PARENTSWID
AND t.LEVEL = cte.LEVEL +1
)
SELECT ID, CATALOGUE, SWID, PARENTSWID, LEVEL FROM cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eecc8/12).

Comment: It will also work with Firebird if the variable is removed and the statement termination character (`;`) is moved to where it belongs: to the end. https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name thank you very much for clarifying this. I am only familiar with sqlserver. And thank you @X.L.Ant for including a fiddle

Comment: this works really nice (on the fiddle) i will just try it with firebird too and give you a feedback.  thanks again :)

Comment: will post it in a new answer